# Can't get Web Scrape to scrape all data needed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to scrape data from this Wikipedia page, I want the column with the years (which happens to be a `<th>`) and the fourth column "Walt Disney Parks and Resort".

**Code:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walt_Disney_Company#Revenues")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

t = open("scrape_project.txt", "w")

year = bsObj.find("table", {"class":"wikitable"}).tr.next_sibling.next_sibling.th
money = bsObj.find("table", {"class":"wikitable"}).td.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling

for year_data in year:
    year.sup.clear()
    print(year.get_text())

for revenue in money:
    print(money.get_text())


t.close()
```

Right now, when I run it through Terminal all that prints is 1991 (twice) and 2,794. I need it to print all of the years and related revenue from Walt Disney Parks and Resorts. I'm also trying to get it to write to the file, "scrape_project.tx"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walt_Disney_Company#Revenues")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

t = open("scrape_project.txt", "w")

table = soup.find('table', {"class": "wikitable"})

# get all rows, skipping first empty
data = table.select("tr")[1:]

# year data is in the scope attribute
years = [td.select("th[scope]")[0].text[:4] for td in data]

# Walt Disney Parks and Resort is the third element in each row
rec = [td.select("td")[2].text for td in data]

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(years)
pp(rec)
```

Which will give you the data:

```
['1991',
 '1992',
 '1993',
 '1994',
 '1995',
 '1996',
 '1997',
 '1998',
 '1999',
 '2000',
 '2001',
 '2002',
 '2003',
 '2004',
 '2005',
 '2006',
 '2007',
 '2008',
 '2009',
 '2010',
 '2011',
 '2012',
 '2013',
 '2014']
['2,794.0',
 '3,306',
 '3,440.7',
 '3,463.6',
 '3,959.8',
 '4,142[Rev 3]',
 '5,014',
 '5,532',
 '6,106',
 '6,803',
 '6,009',
 '6,691',
 '6,412',
 '7,750',
 '9,023',
 '9,925',
 '10,626',
 '11,504',
 '10,667',
 '10,761',
 '11,797',
 '12,920',
 '14,087',
 '15,099']
```

I sliced the revision off with `text[:4]`, if you want to keep the info then don't slice. If you want to also remove from the money i.e remove Rev 3 from `'4,142[Rev 3]'`, you can use a regex:

```
import re

m = re.compile("\d+,\d+")

rec = [m.search(td.select("td")[2].text).group() for td in data]
```

Which will give you:

```
['2,794',
 '3,306',
 '3,440',
 '3,463',
 '3,959',
 '4,142',
 '5,014',
 '5,532',
 '6,106',
 '6,803',
 '6,009',
 '6,691',
 '6,412',
 '7,750',
 '9,023',
 '9,925',
 '10,626',
 '11,504',
 '10,667',
 '10,761',
 '11,797',
 '12,920',
 '14,087',
 '15,099']
```

Answer (score -1):

There has to be a cleaner way to get into there, but this will do.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walt_Disney_Company#Revenues")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable"})

rows = [row for row in table.findAll("th", {"scope":"row"})]

for each in rows:
    string = each.text[:4] + ", $" + \
          each.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
```